# Entity Framework: How to prevent overwrite "StoreGeneratedPattern" attribute on update model?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

In the MSDN ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738536%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) it is clearly stated that EDMGen.exe is not generating the StoreGeneratedPattern attribute. So I have to add this attribute manually. I can live with that.

The problem that I have is that the properties of the EntityTypes get overwritten on every "update my model from the database". So I have to undo these changes on every type in my model after an update.

Is there a way to prevent this automatic update of my model?

Comment: Are you using designer for updating?

Comment: Yes, I use the designer for updating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [this fix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2561001). It was initially fixed in VS 2010 SP1 but the fix wasn't complete because many people still had this problem. This fix should solve the problem.

Comment: This fix solves the problem! The settings will only be overwritten for the entity that has been refreshed! Thank you!

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka The link is broken can you please give the new link

Comment: @mohit: Try the new link.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Thanks but solved the problem using Metadata attribute